# Check if a variable exists within local scope by name as string?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to find out if there is a variable that exists in the local scope with a given name as a string. Is there way to do something like this?:

```
var name = 'myVariable';

function test(myVariable) {

     //CHECK HERE if there is a locally scoped variable with the same name
     //as the value of 'name' 

}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible (assuming you intend to check similarly to `window[myVariable]` as is possible for a global variable), unless, perhaps, there's some means of applying a name-space, maybe? I'd like to be wrong about this, however.

Comment: What's the actual use-case? Does it need to work across browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to piggyback on Bandrami's answer and my comment as I believe it to be the only way to accomplish what you are trying to do. Yes, I know that I'm using `eval`, but I don't believe there is any option.

```
if (typeof eval(name) !== 'undefined' && typeof window[name] === 'undefined'){ 
   // variable exists in this scope 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (typeof eval(name) === 'undefined')
```

Though there are some corner cases there (like a variable actually named 'undefined')...

(Or I may be completely missing your point...)

Comment: I think typeof will not return undefined if the variable exists in global (or any higher level) scope, if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: Yes, it will return true if the variable is in the global scope, you could alter this to be: `if (typeof eval(name) !== 'undefined' && typeof window[name] === 'undefined'){ // exists in this scope }`

Comment: @echochamber Danke. :)

Comment: Thanks Brandami. That's pretty cool but it doesn't quite do it I think. If this function was inside another function it would pick up variable within the closure. Also if there variables of the same name locally and globally...

Comment: @Teemu you've said that 3 times already, now please explain why it doesn't make sense.