# Javascript, getting away from 'this' and using local scope

Tags: javascript

In a typical js class, all calls to member functions must be preceded by `this`. I was looking at a technique that would let me create a library of inter-dependent STATIC functions and relying on closure/scope to make things a bit easier.

Example:

```
var Singleton={
  //main entry point
  // call with fn name, args...
  call:function(){
    var args=[];
    if (arguments.length==0) {
      return;
    }
    // get the fn name
    var fn=arguments[0];
    var x;
    // make args array
    for (x=1;x<arguments.length;x++) {
      args[args.length]=arguments[x];
    }
    // I want to get rid of this part
    // See below for what I wish
    // Here I have access to fns below due to hoisting in js
    // so I put them in a map...
    var fns={
      test:test
      // etc, more like this I do not want to type/maintain
    }
    // ... all so I can do this
    // get my function.
    var fun=fns[fn];
    // instead of that, I would like to "override whitespace" and
    // say something like:
    // var fun=['fn_name'];
    // so I can index into local scope and get a fn
    //
    // log error if not found
    if (typeof fun=='undefined') {
      loge('Singleton: function not found:'+fn);
      return;
    }
    // ok, run the function
    return fun.apply(window,args);
    // the test fn accesses test2() without dot notation
    function test(a){
      // Note: here in test fn it can access test2() 
      // without using this.test2() syntax
      // as you would in normal objects
      var s=test2();
      alert(s+' test:'+a);
    };
    function test2(){
      return 'test2';
    };
  }
}
```

I was hoping someone more familiar with advances in javascript might have advice on how to emulate an "implied but unnecessary `this`", it always struck me as strange that `this` defaults to window, and wouldn't it be nice if `this` could be pointed to an anonymous object with the local scope attached.

I would love to say `['localObject']` to get something in scope.

## Edit:

After seeing some of the responses, I will restate this in the form of a challenge:

What I am looking for is a syntax cheat, a way to, as @Varuna put it, "1. Access static methods without using this variable i.e. they will remain global to one another. 2. Do not want to maintain a local array for static methods and want to achieve with in the local scope itself."

Put differently, I need to have the declared functions Register themselves, but I don't want to state the function name more than once. I suppose @Varuna has a solution using `eval` to access the local scope.

The following approach wont work:

```
var o={};
o['fn']=function fn(){};
o['fn2']=function fn2(){};
```

...because you have to state the fn name twice, but closure is preserved.

And this:

```
var a=[
  function fn(){}
  ,function fn2(){}
];
Register(a);
```

Will not work because, AFAIK, you lose closure, ie. fn2 cannot see fn. Which also makes the following declarative style a "`this` nightmare":

```
window.MINE={
  fn:function fn(){
    //this?
    // want to say fn2(), not this.fn2(), nor MINE.fn2()
  }
  ,fn2:function fn2(){
    //this?
  }
  ,deeper:{
    //more
  }
};
```

But something like this might work, if you created a weird property that does the registration on assignment:

```
var registar=new Registar();
registar.reg=function fn(){};
registar.reg=function fn2(){};
//then access
var fn=registar.getFn(n);
// or
var fn=registar._[n];
```

The above relies on js properties and having access to fn.name, which is not available in all cases AFAIK.

Comment: var localObject=this;

Comment: You can create all your accessors in an IIFE, then reference them in local scope, although you will need to explicitly attach an interface to the public object.

Comment: Um, you're not calling any member functions at all, so what's your problem with `this`?

Comment: I have gone into more detail with an edit. @JimmyBreck-McKye

Comment: Thank you for the update. No, there is no implicit `this` in javascript. But what's so wrong with using it? Especially when you to need to have the function on an object to access them by name anyway, this would be the simplest solution.

Comment: @Bergi The problem is when you are creating a group of inter-dependent STATIC functions (fns that do not need/use `this`, but rely on closure to see each other) -- then, when you try to encapsulate these functions (take them out of global scope by some mechanism), you must inject `this` before refs to other functions, OR put them all into their own private scope AND create a map to pull them out. What I want is something closer to the `eval` solution posted here. I do not want to maintain a map.

Comment: But you *should* maintain a map anyway, to distinguish private from public static functions. There is no other solution, sorry (assuming you don't want to use black `eval` magic).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to create objects that:

- have static members
- ... which can be accessed without using the this notation

The easiest solution (assuming I've properly understood your query), would be to simply use a closure to store your stratic fields, access them directly by name, then explicitly add them as object members.

Consider:

```
var myConstructor = (function(){

    var foo = 'someStaticField';
    var bar = function(){
        alert('A static method returns ' + foo);
    };

    return function(){
        return {
            foo : foo,
            bar : bar
        };
    };

})();
var myInstance = new myConstructor();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about *declaring* functions that can access each other in separate closure, and exporting them to main method by binding your `call` method to an object containing the functions? Something like previous post (modified slightly):

```
var Singleton = {

  call: (function() {

    // here 'call' is bound to object containig your test functions
    // this: {test, test2}

    if (0 == arguments.length) return;

    // log error if not found
    if ('function' != typeof this[arguments[0]]) {
      console.warn('Singleton: function not found:' + arguments[0]);
      return;
    }

    // '...index into local scope and get function 
    // ie. get the function by it's name
    return this[arguments[0]].
      apply(window, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));




    // --- or:


    // you can explicitly introduce function names to current scope, 
    // by `eval`-ing them here (not very much preferred way in JavaScript world):

    for (var fname in this) 
      if (this.hasOwnProperty(fname)) 
        eval('var ' + fname + ' = ' + this[fname]);


    // and you can reference them directly by using their names

    var fn = eval(arguments[0]);        
    return fn.apply(window, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));



  }).bind(

    (function() {


      var _exports = {};


      function test (a) {
        var s = test2();
        alert(s + ' test: ' + a);
      }

      function test2 () {
        return 'test2';
      }



      _exports['test']  = test;
      _exports['test2'] = test2;


      return _exports;


    })()

  )};

  Singleton.call('test', 'foo and stuff');
  //
```

---

**previous post:**

You are talking about `Function#bind` functionality that enables 'customizing' function's context. `.bind()` your `call` method to required 'local context' like this:

```
var Singleton = {

  //main entry point
  // call with fn name, args...
  call: (function() {

    // here `this` (context) is object bound to `call` method
    // not `global` object, which is default for 'unbound' functions

    var locals = this; // {fns, shift, loge, isfunc}

    var fn;
    var fun;
    var x;

    if (arguments.length == 0)
      return;

    // get the fn name
    fn = locals.shift(arguments);

    // '...index into local scope and get a fn'
    fun = locals.fns[fn];

    // log error if not found
    if (!locals.isfunc(fun)) {
      locals.loge('Singleton: function not found:' + fn);
      return;
    }
    // ok, run the function
    return fun.apply(window, arguments);

  // lock `call`'s context to provided object
  // and use `this` to reference it inside `call`
  }).bind({

    fns: (function(_) {

      // and you can '...create a library of inter-dependent STATIC functions' 
      // in this closure and invoke them in `call` method above

      _.test = function (a) {
        var s = _.test2();
        alert(s + ' test: ' + a);
      };

      _.test2 = function() {
        return 'test2';
      };

      return _;
    })({}),

    // and create couple of helper methods as well...

    isfunc: (function(_getclass) {

      _getclass.func = _getclass(_getclass);

      return ('function' !== typeof(/foo/)) ?
        function(node) {
          return 'function' == typeof node;
      } :
        function(node) {
          return _getclass.func === _getclass(node);
      };
    })(Function.prototype.call.bind(Object.prototype.toString)),

    loge: console.warn,

    shift: Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.shift)

  }),

};

Singleton.call('test', 'foo and stuff');


// eof
```

Comment: That looks interesting, I would have to study it further to figure out what its really doing. What I don't like about it is that fn.name is not preserved, and you have to use `_.fn` within the functions -- which is what I was trying to get away from in the first place. I don't need a `this` except to acquire an actual function given its name. See my Edit for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you want to:
 1. Access static methods without using this variable i.e. they will remain global to one another.
 2. Do not want to maintain a local array for static methods and want to achieve with in the local scope itself.

You can check whether a method exist using eval.Check [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433668/check-if-a-variable-exists-within-local-scope-by-name-as-string)

Only drawback is that this will be using eval method.
Code will be:

```
var Singleton = {
        //main entry point
        // call with fn name, args...
        call: function () {
            var args = [];
            if (arguments.length == 0) {
                return;
            }
            // get the fn name
            var fn = arguments[0];
            var x;
            // make args array
            for (x = 1; x < arguments.length; x++) {
                args[args.length] = arguments[x];
            }

            //check whether function exist in local scope and not in global scope
            if (typeof eval(fn) !== 'undefined' && typeof window[fn] === 'undefined') {
                // ok, run the function
                return eval(fn).apply(window, args);
            }
            else{
                // log error if not found                
                loge('Singleton: function not found:' + fn);
                return;
            }

            // the test fn accesses test2() without dot notation
            function test(a) {
                // Note: here in test fn it can access test2() 
                // without using this.test2() syntax
                // as you would in normal objects
                var s = test2();
                alert(s + ' test:' + a);
            };
            function test2() {
                return 'test2';
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: I like this, it seems that `eval` can always be the answer to anything in a pinch, but in this case it didn't occur to me because I try to pretend `eval` doesn't exist due to its drawbacks, but in this application it is a pretty clean solution. `eval(undefined)==42` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one 'in your face answer', because I really don't like what I see here.
I don't see why you need this kind of construct, you already have that as part of language core.

**1. dynamic lookup**
  you are doing it in a rather 'unprecedented' kind of way, 
  hashes already do that for you, and it's lightning fast to do a hash search.
  If you are `eval()`-ing random strings to do simple name lookup you really have to 
  step aside from a keybord for a while... (no offense please)

**2. closures**
  you are saying about 'using closures' which you actualy don't use. 
  your `call` function redeclares test functions each time it gets called, 
  and looks the ('fresh version') functions in it's own variable scope table, 
  instead of lookig them up in parent scope chains (aka. closures)
  outside it's lexical location

**3. nfe vs. nfd**
  ie. *named function expressions* vs. *named function declarations*
  *...you cannot assign a function to a local var and have it retain closure*.
  It is a feature, you might not be aware of how it works (it tripped me up as well).
  check [this article](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/) out for clarification

**4. exceptions**
  *Singleton: function name not found*... **x4!**
  Just go ahead and call a function, 
  interpreter will throw for you anyway if it cannot find/execute

**5. eval (aka. ^^)**
  `Singleton.call.ctx.fun = eval(Singleton.call.ctx.fn);`
  eval takes **any** string here(#!), and gladly executes ones like: 
  `'for(;;);'`, or `'while(1);'`... forever. 
  You probably don't want to have any code running unless it was your stuff.

**6. arguments handling**
  It is considered *best practice* out there to use single `(Object) options` parameter 
  to 'fine tune' any significant piece of bundled functionality, 
  instead of trying to figure that out by type checking provided argument list

Here's, in couple of simple lines, what I (and as I can see @Jimmy Breck-McKye) suggest you should do:

```
var Singleton.call = (function () {


  var funcmap = {
    'f_1': function () {}, 
    // etc.
    'f_N': function () {},
  };


  return function (options) {

    // options members:
    //   context, (Object) context, (defaults to global if none is given)
    //   func,    (String) function_name, 
    //   args,    (Array)  arguments to pass into a function


    // this line does everything your 100+ lines long snippet was trying to:
    // look's up parent scope for a function, tries to run it 
    // passing provided data, throws if it gets stuck.
    return funcmap[options.func].apply(options.context, options.args);
  };

})();
//
```

Comment: Two points- 1) this is mostly a transitional type of mechanism, a refactoring mechanism. The use case is I have a group of interdependent functions I have worked up in global scope, and I wish to loosely package them without having to inject the this pointer into their function bodies. 2) In your code the functions you have in your map cannot see each other, SO I would have to use funcmap in place of the this pointer in their function bodies. In other words, AFAIK, this is the only way to drag a bunch of functions out of global scope and have them work without having to wire them up.

Comment: well, if you have them available **globaly**, then they are automatically available in any scope (unless _cloacked_ by the same local variable names) right? And you can reference them dynamically by indexing global object.

Comment: @nicolav Correct. But I do not **want** them in global scope any longer. This aims to allow related functions to **cluster** and allow me to discover which of them needs to be publicly accessible as development proceeds.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here.

The core of the issue is that you cannot assign a function to a local var and have it retain closure.

Consider that when writing a function with global and window scope, `this` is not necessary to call another function with identical scope. Such is not the case with member functions.

Another way of saying this is that there is no space where your cursor can sit and as you declare a function it automatically gets attached to the current `this`.

```
function fn(){}// if we are in global scope, then window.fn becomes defined
// but if we are inside, say, a constructor, simple declaration will not attach
// it to this, but fn is available in scope.
```

Any assignment on function declaration BREAKS part of the expected closure:

```
var IdentifierAvailableToClosure=function Unavailable(){}
```

But assignment after declaration works:

```
function NowAvailable(){}
var SynonymAvailableToo=NowAvailable;
```

This is what I meant by not wanting to repeat the name twice to get the mechanism to work.

This fact made me abandon other methods and rely on `eval` as suggested. Here is a first draft:

```
// This object is an encapsulation mechanism for a group of
// inter-dependent, static-ish, functions that can call each other
// without a this pointer prefix.
// Calls take the form of:
// Singleton.call(functionName:String [,arg1]...)
// or
// Singleton.call(contextObject:Object, functionName:String [,arg1]...)
// If a context is not provided, window is used.
//
// This type of mechanism is useful when you have defined a group
// of functions in the window/global scope and they are not ready
// to be formalized into a set of classes, or you have no intention
// of doing that
//
// To illustrate the issue, consider that a function
// which is defined in window/global scope
// does not have to use the this pointer to call a function of
// identical scope -- yet in a class member function, the this pointer
// MUST be used
// Therefore, trying to package such functions requires injecting
// the this pointer into function bodies where calls to associater
// functions are made
//
// Usage is primarily for development where one has control over
// global namespace pollution and the mechanism is useful in
// refactoring prior to formalization of methods into classes
var Singleton={
  // Main call point
  call:function(){
    // Bail with error if no args
    if (arguments.length==0) {
      throw('Singleton: need at least 1 arg');
    }
    // As all functions in the local scope library below
    // have access to the local scope via closure, we want to reduce
    // pollution here, so lets attach locals to this call
    // function instead of declaring locals
    //
    // Prepare to call anon fn
    Singleton.call.args=arguments;
    // Make ctx have args, context object, and function name
    Singleton.call.ctx=(function (){// return args,ctx,name
      // out
      var args=[];
      //locals
      var x, fn;
      // collapse identifier
      var a=Singleton.call.args;
      // closure object avail to functions, default to window
      that=window;
      // first real function argument
      var arg_start=1;
      // first arg must be function name or object
      if (typeof a[0]=='string') {// use window ctx
        fn=a[0];
      // if first arg is object, second is name
      }else if (typeof a[0]=='object') {
        // assign given context
        that=a[0];
        // check second arg for string, function name
        if (typeof a[1]!='string') {
          var err='Singleton: second argument needs to be a fn name'
                 +' when first arg is a context object';
          throw(err)
          return;
        }
        // ok, have a name
        fn=a[1];
        // args follow
        arg_start=2;
      }else{
        // improper arg types
        var err='Singleton: first argument needs to be a string or object';
        throw(err)
      }
      // build args array for function
      for (x=arg_start;x<a.length;x++) {
        args[args.length]=a[x];
      }
      // return context
      return {
        args: args
        ,that:that
        ,fn:fn
      };
    })();
    // using function library present in local scope, try to find specified function
    try{
      Singleton.call.ctx.fun=eval(Singleton.call.ctx.fn);
    }catch (e){
      console.error('Singleton: function name not found:' + Singleton.call.ctx.fn);
      throw('Singleton: function name not found:' + Singleton.call.ctx.fn);
    }
    // it must be a function
    if (typeof Singleton.call.ctx.fun !== 'function') {
      console.error('Singleton: function name not found:' + Singleton.call.ctx.fn);
      throw('Singleton: function name not found:' + Singleton.call.ctx.fn);
    }
    // library functions use that instead of this
    // that is visible to them due to closure
    var that=Singleton.call.ctx.that;
    // Do the call!
    return Singleton.call.ctx.fun.apply(that, Singleton.call.ctx.args);
    //
    // cool library of functions below,
    // functions see each other through closure and not through this.fn
    function test(s){
      alert(test2()+' test:'+s);
    }
    function info_props(){
      console.info(this_props());
    }
    function test2(){
      return 'test2';
    }
    function this_props(){
      var s='';
      for (var i in that) {
        s+=' '+i;
      }
      return s;
    };
  }
};
```